# Error "Import Command Not Found" while doing examples of service and client using rospy in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros, rospy, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While doing the example of Service and Client from this page, I am getting an error "Import Command not Found" when trying to run the Server and the Client Nodes. I have checked the code but evrything is acoording to the tutorial. Can somebody please help? I am doing these examples using rospy.

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29

The file is as below :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy

from beginner_tutorials.srv import *

def handle_add_two_ints(req):
  print "Returning [%s + %s = %s]"%(req.a, req.b, (req.a + req.b))
  return AddTwoIntsResponse(req.a + req.b)

def add_two_ints_server():
  rospy.init_node('add_two_ints_server')
  s = rospy.Service('add_two_ints', AddTwoInts, handle_add_two_ints)
  print "Ready to add two ints."
  rospy.spin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  add_two_ints_server()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190816/error-%22import-command-not-found%22-while-doing-examples-of-service-and-client-using-rospy-in-ubuntu-12.04./) by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2014-08-21

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-08-21**:
Yes. I have run catkin_make and source devel/setup.bash. Infact, I have been able to sucessfully run the publish, subscribe messages tutorial in python. So, I guess python has been set up properly.

Edit :  python filename.py as suggested by one of the users has worked without any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you remembered to do a `catkin_make`, then `source devel/setup.bash` before running the examples?

Without the proper environment setup, Python is not going to be able to find the ROS imports.

---

Edit:

Right. Two things: please don't use answers to answer someone else's answer (:)). Use comments for that. Also: please update your original question with the contents of the file you are trying to run (please use formatting for that: indent every line with 4 spaces).

Lastly: searching for `Import Command not Found` shows a lot of pages recommending me to make sure I have `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of my file. Do you? The error is probably really `import: command not found`, right?

---

Edit2: I've fixed the formatting a bit.

1. Can you confirm that your file is exactly like this?
2. How do you exactly run your node?
3. Have you made your file executable (ie: `chmod +x filename.py`)?
4. What is the output if you do `python filename.py` (change `filename.py` to the actual name)
5. Did you by any chance create the file in Windows (running Ubuntu in a VM)? If so, could you try `fromdos filename.py` and see if the console output changes?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-08-21**:
Yes, I have added that line at the top of the file as you can see. But, it is still giving the error. The error is "Import: Command Not Found". Don't know what is missing.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-21**:
Are the line numbers also in your file? Those are not supposed to be there. Please make sure the question contains a direct copy/paste from the file you are trying to execute.

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-08-21**:
No. The line numbers are not there in the file.

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-08-21**:
Thanks. python filename.py command has worked. Strangely, rosrun did not seem to be running. Thanks again.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-21**:
Could you answer all 5 questions please? The fact that `python filename.py` worked is just an indication that something isn't right with your file, and it is most likely the *shebang* line (the `#!/usr/bin/env python`).

**Comment by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on 2014-08-21**:\

1. Yes the file is exactly like this
2. rosrun [package name] [executablefile.py]
3. Yes I have run chmod +x filename.py
4. Yes, I have ubuntu installed on VB. fromdos filename.py does not seem to do anything. No output.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-21**:
But did you use a windows editor to create the file (via a shared folder fi)? `fromdos filename.py` is not supposed to give any output. It converts line-endings from DOS/Windows files into Unix line-endings. Could you now (after having done `fromdos filename.py`) try just doing `./filename.py` now, or even `rosrun pkg filename.py`?